# Como colocar banner rotativo com imagens num site responsivo?

Tags: jquery, layout-responsivo

Fiz um banner rotativo com jQuery no Dreamweaver para um site responsivo.

Quando visualizado no Desktop ele fica perfeito, mas quando quando altero para *mobile* ou *tablet* as fotos ficam **distorcidas**.

Como faço para que as imagens do banner rotativo funcionem em todas as plataformas?

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor que tipo de distorção ocorre, bem como a versão do jQuery e o plug-in de banner rotativo que você está usando, e também postar um trecho de código para avaliação

Comment: As imagens ficam estreitas, pra se adaptar a largura da plataforma. A versão do jquery é a 1.11.1 e plug-in cycle.

Comment: Pela descrição do problema, acho que isso possa ser resolvido forçando uma altura variável no banner; `height: auto !important;`

Comment: Rebeca, bem-vinda ao [pt.so]! Seria muito interessante você postar os trechos de código para que os usuários pudessem testar reproduzir o problema. Sem saber como você fez a implementação, fica muito vago dar uma resposta conclusiva sobre como resolver o problema. Poderia, por favor, editar a sua pergunta acrescentando essas informações?

Comment: Você usa esse http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ ? Pois no próprio site no tópico **Responsive** ele mostra como fazer isso...

Comment: Eu não usava esse, Rafael. Agora sim deu certo, utilizava um plug-in que não se adequava a sites responsivos. Muito obrigada! :D

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, gente.